# Anyway to link a dll compiled using c++ builder in vc++ code?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, c++builder, dllimport

I did some google and all I find is ways to make a vc++ dll compatible to c++ builder via COFF2OMF. But I need to bring a c+ builder dll into vc++. Is there any similar tool that creates a vc++ compatible .lib from a c++ builder dll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just recompile it using the compiler you want to use.

Comment: I can't do that. There are some vcl headers from c++ builder.

Comment: What are trying to import? If you want to import classes that will never work.

Comment: @Cody Yes, proprietary extensions to the language are used

Comment: If I use a c++ clr is there a way to capture the class pointer returned from the native c++ dll?

Answer (score 0):

If the interface of your DLL (functions that have been exported) does not depend on VCL and object pascal, you can do one on the to methods below:

1. extract a .LIB from the DLL by using the methods described [here](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/)
   and linking the generated .LIB into your project.
2. Use [LoadLibrary()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx), [GetProcAddress()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) to dynamically load the DLL and use the exported functions.

keep in mind that your DLL might be dependent on VCL libraries and ... which makes using them more difficult. also I have to say it again, if any VCL or object pascal data is being used in the exported functions, you will not be able to use this DLL at all.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

`COFF2OMF.EXE` is the wrong way to use a VC++ DLL in C++Builder. It should only be used when converting a **static LIB**. It is not necessary for a **DLL import LIB**. You should use `IMPLIB.EXE` instead to generate a new C++Builder compatible import LIB from the DLL directly.

The VC++ equivalent is to use `DUMPBIN.EXE` to list the DLL exports, then write a `.DEF` file defining those exports, and then run the `.DEF` through `LIB.EXE` to create a VC++ compatible import LIB.

See this blog for more details:

[Create .lib file from .dll](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/)